# How to implement chat head in android app

Tags: android

How to make an app capable of making chat head(floating window) like a Facebook chat head or WhatsApp reply? That popup should be able to launch itself when a certain action is completed,   over any screen even when the app is not running.

Comment: Could you provide a image of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It just like Facebook chat head

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your utils class:

```
public static void showPopUp(Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxml, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(v);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create(); 
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Call the above method by using `YOURUTILSCLASSNAME.showPopUp(YOURACTIVITY.this);` in whereever you want to show the popup.

Comment: I don't want to create alert dialog.. I wanted to make Facebook chat head kind of thing..

Comment: Refer this it may help you      https://blackmoont92.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/android-chathead-tutorial/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the formatting help available in the entry box. Formatting helps others more easily read and understand.